# drag and drop in Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, canvas

I'm doing an application in flex where I draw different sprites inside a canvas. Depending of the dimensions, scrollbars can be appear. I would like to move the "image" with the movement of the mouse as you can see at the Adobe Reader when you are reading a document with zoom (hand mouse icon). In this way, you dont have to touch the scrollbar.

I'm start trying with drag and drop properties of the canvas, setting the position of the scrollbar according with the movement of the mouse but that is not as I expect.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recipe:

1. Listen for the `mouseMove` (`MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE`) event on the canvas
2. In event listener, examine `event.localX`, `event.localY`
3. Based on those values and the canvas's `width` and `height`, set the canvas's `horizontalScrollPosition` and `verticalScrollPosition` accordingly

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I use a handle of the mouseMove, MouseDown and MouseUp events to know which it's the first point and the second. And depending of the difference between then I made a scroll movement towards the top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, change the position of the scrollbar , when the mouse reaches the last 20 pixels on the left or the right, or the top and bottom.

What you would really need to do is, have a mouseMove listener on the whole application, and when the mouse is within the end ranges of any of the sides, you can use the scroll.scrollTo function to move the scrollbars.